# How to avoid datasource security permission issues when using Flyway?

Tags: spring-boot, database-migration, flyway

For my upcoming microservice deployments I intend to use **spring-boot** and  **Flyway** as the database migration tool. For security reasons I need to draw a line between the **DDL** schema creation parts (create, alter, drop table etc.) and accessing the **DML** data (select, insert, update, delete) stored inside the Oracle db.

I was thinking of using two different datasources, the first used solely for Flyway operations and the second for the real application.

I havent't found a best practise implementation to solve this problem yet. Any advice or link would be very helpful.

Comment: What is it that the default support cannot do for you? Have you read [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup).

Comment: Thank you, that has been the missing link. This information was missing on the Flyway documentation pages.

Comment: @KaiLüdersdorff Feel free to submit a PR or open an issue against flyway/flywaydb.org with your view on how things should be improved.